# Ruby: How can i access method inside a module>module>class

Tags: ruby

Suppose there is a code like that :

```
module A
  module AB
    class ABC
      def one
        ....
      end

      def two
        ...
      end
.........
.........
```

Now how can i access method "one" , "two" etc from other ruby file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call the method like this:

```
A::AB::ABC.new.one
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to access these methods ?

Comment: Sure, you can `include A::AB` and then `ABC.new.one`.